# Pivot_wider function (tidyr r package) from multiple variables

Tags: r, pivot, tidy

I would like to put the dataframe in the wide format considering two variables as criteria (maybe even unnecessary). But I comment on this because the original df is 480 rows and several sub-levels.

This is returning an error!

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
                                                                
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4), Gender = c("Men", "Women", "Men", 
"Women"), Country = c("Austria", "Austria", "Austria", "Austria"
), Season_ID = c("2011", "2012", "2011", "2012"), Region_UN = c("A", 
"B", "A", "B")), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

df_wide <- df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Gender,
              values_from = Region_UN,
              id_cols = c(Country, Season_ID))
```

Warning message:
Values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.

- Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
- Use `values_fn = length` to identify where the duplicates arise
- Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates

I don't know which argument I could put in values_fn!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create a sequence column

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
df %>% 
  mutate(ID = NULL, rn = rowid(Country, Season_ID)) %>%     
  pivot_wider(names_from = Gender,
          values_from = Region_UN,
          id_cols = c(rn, Country, Season_ID))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked perfectly

Comment: What is the advantage of the sequential column?

Comment: If there are duplicates for id_cols,  it wouldn't know which row the duplicate should be handled.  sequential column make it unique to give the location for each element

Answer (score 6):

You can also paste it together:

```
df_wide <- df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Gender,
              values_from = Region_UN,
              id_cols = c(Country, Season_ID),
              values_fn = function(x) paste(x, collapse=","))

df_wide
```

and as both are the same also:

```
df_wide <- df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Gender,
              values_from = Region_UN,
              id_cols = c(Country, Season_ID),
              values_fn = first)
df_wide
```

Comment: Thanks. The second option is the best.